# Exercise 2.27 Atiyah-Macdonald, absolute flatness

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

A commutative ring $R$ is absolutely flat if every $R$-module is flat. Prove that the following are equivalent:

1) $R$ is absolutely flat

2) Every principal ideal of $R$ is idempotent

3) Every finitely generated ideal of $R$ is a direct summand

I'm stuck on implication $1) \to 2) $

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal in a ring $A$ and $M$ is an $A$-module, then the map
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
M\otimes_A A/\mathfrak a &\to& M/\mathfrak aM \\
m\otimes (a+\mathfrak a)&\mapsto& ma+\mathfrak a M
\end{array}
$$
is an isomorphism, which we will call the **quotienting isomorphism**. Proving this map is an isomorphism is exactly [Exercise 2.2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301602/isomorphism-between-tensor-product-and-quotient-module) in Atiyah-Macdonald.

Now, suppose $R$ is absolutely flat and let $x\in R$. Then 
$$
0\to (x)\to R\to R/(x)\to 0\tag{1}
$$
is exact in $_{R}\mathsf{Mod}$. Since $R/(x)$ is flat, applying $(-)\otimes_R R/(x)$ to (1) gives an exact sequence
$$
0\to (x)\otimes_R R/(x)\to R\otimes_R R/(x)\to R/(x)\otimes_R R/(x)\to 0
$$
in $_{R}\mathsf{Mod}$. One then shows that the diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0&\to& (x)\otimes_R R/(x)&\to &R\otimes_R R/(x)&\to &R/(x)\otimes_R R/(x)&\to& 0 \\
&&\downarrow && \downarrow && \downarrow \\
0&\to& (x)/(x)^2&\to& R/(x)&=& R/(x)&\to& 0
\end{array}\tag{2}
$$
commutes where the vertical arrows are the quotienting isomorphisms. This implies that the bottom row of (2) is exact so $(x)/(x)^2=0$ as required.

Answer (score 5):

What happens if you tensor the short exact sequence $$0\to I\to R\to R/I\to 0$$ with $I$?

Comment: Dear Mariano, I can't find an answer to your question which would solve the problem. Could you please add some details?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: For any ideals $I, J$, $\operatorname{Tor}^R_1(R/I,R/J) \cong (I \cap J)/IJ$.

Comment: @zcn: what does what you write have  to do with Mariano's answer, who tensors with $I$ ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Ah, I missed that part. In that case, I believe Mariano means: tensor with $R/I$

Answer (score 0):

I'll put in the picture because I could not write the diagram in latex[image]