# $m\mathbb{Z}\cdot \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I'm trying to find the tensor product $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ using [this theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301602/isomorphism-between-tensor-product-and-quotient-module).
Now I know what the end product is (namely: $\mathbb{Z}/\gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$) and I proved it differently. However,

> how do I get that $m\mathbb{Z}\cdot \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\cong \gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: For my own learning, I am wondering what does $m\mathbb{Z} \cdot \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ mean? It is not a tensor product?

Comment: @Mike $\{k\cdot l \mid k\in m\mathbb{Z}, l\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, if $I$ and $J$ are ideals of the commutative ring $R$, we have
$$
I\cdot R/J=(I+J)/J
$$
The proof is easier to formalize in the more abstract setting and is a simple verification.

In your case $I=m\mathbb{Z}$ and $J=n\mathbb{Z}$, so
$$
I+J=m\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}=\gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}
$$

Comment: Where can I find a proof for this general case?

Comment: @UnexpectedExpectation Let $x\in I$ and $y\in R$; then $x(y+J)=xy+J\in (I+J)/J$. Let $x\in I$, $y\in J$. Then $(x+y)+J=x+J=x(1+J)\in I\cdot R/J$.